# Switching hosting provider. Preserve emails?

Tags: web-hosting

We're looking to switch our domain and hosting provider to a company that gives a little more freedom and is less of a financial burden. However, we cannot afford to have any disruption to email service - the emails are part of the current hosting package.

Is there a way we can switch our hosting provider without email disruption? Or is it a matter of 'out of business hours' switching?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

Once you switch your MX entries your email will start arriving in the new place. However people who have the old entries cached will still send to the old place. Providing you can pick up your email from both places you'll be alright. After 3 days all email should be arriving at the new place.

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS records will be cached, including your MX entries. Setting up your DNS should be possible, i.e. to get them to point somewhere else, but you might not have a control panel for that, in which case you'll be doing this on Sunday night.

Answer (score 0):

Please following these steps

1. Setup an email account with GMAIL and then set GMAIL to read in your emails from the hosted mail service. This provides a backup if something goes astray during the transfer process.
2. Simply setup with the new hosting provider before cancelling the ole one, change your NameServer details and within 48 hours you will start receiving and sending mail through your new proivder. Use the IP address or mail.yourprovider.com to download any residual mail received at your old provider.
3. Check your backup gmail account as it will get all copies and be one of the first once the nameservers change.
4. Cancel your old hosting provider.